# Calculate the chars incorrectly

Tags: javascript

```
jQuery ( function ( $ ) {   

    var textarea = $('.project');
    var $counter = $('.chars');

    var limit = 200;
    var initial = 0;

    $(textarea).on('keypress keyup copy paste', function(){
        displayLength();
    });



function displayLength() {
     var thisChars = textarea.val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').length; 

    if (thisChars > limit) {
        //$counter.text(thisChars + ' of 200 chars');
        var CharsToDel = (thisChars-limit); 

         textarea.val() = textarea.val().substring(0,textarea.val().length-CharsToDel);


    } else {
        $counter.text(initial + thisChars +' of 200 chars 2');

    }
}
    displayLength();

    });
```

The issue is that it calculates chars incorrectly. if limit is 200, it should be cut (with substring) to 200 chars instead of printing 201 chars. why?

**Update**
Managed to get it working, thanks everybody

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not just `textarea.value.substring(0, 200)`?

Comment: Is "Miscalculate the chars incorrectly" a weird logical expression  of "calculate correctly"?

Comment: totalChars doesn't exist anywhere except when you use it to calculate CharsToDel

Comment: @CD - you right i will try

Comment: "[...]there are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors." http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Comment: 0 - 200 = 201 chars. `thisChar > limit` returns false on 200. Either set the limit at 199 or use `>='.

Comment: @UKatz - unfortunately it doesnt work :(

Comment: @erikrunia - im aware and i replace it with limit

Comment: This line has the exact same problem as I mentioned before (sorry I did not see it): `textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,textarea.value.length-CharsToDel)`. 

Change the following line to: `var CharsToDel = (thisChars-totalChars - 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textarea` is a jQuery object, not an html element - so you want to use `.val()` rather than `.value`

Instead of this:

```
textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,textarea.value.length-CharsToDel);
```

try:

```
textarea.val(textarea.val().substr(0,textarea.val().length-CharsToDel));
```

[Click for a working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamh/Ck7xs/)

Comment: tried another way but the result is that it is doing nothing or returning empty.

Answer (score 1):

> The [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method returns a subset of a string between one
>   index and another, or through the end of the string.

```
str.substring(indexA[, indexB])
```

> substring extracts characters from indexA up to but not including
>   indexB.

So you just need to do:

```
textarea.val().substring(0, 200)
```

Comment: Does `substring` ignore line breaks, etc - as per the original code?

Comment: @Cd - tried substring(0,limit) but it returns error ' cannot call method 'substring' of undefined

Comment: @adam, it does ignore line breaks and have tested with doc to compare the number of chars